# extjs numberfield without defaultValue

Tags: extjs

My model has a field with definition as below.

```
{
    name: 'ed_price',
    type: 'number'
}
```

The column in the Grid Panel has a editor config as

```
editor:  {
     xtype: 'numberfield'
}
```

I have celledit enabled on the Grid with a single click. When I click on this column for Edit, I see a default Value 0 in the numberfield. How can I remove it ?

I have tried the below configs on the field definition.

```
defaultValue: null,
allowNull: true

defaultValue: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `useNull : true` to your model field, after that set default value to null

Comment: 'allowNull' is what is available in ExtJS 5. I've tried that, as mentioned above.

Comment: I thought you tried it with editor field. Do you have some fiddle to test this behaviour?